# Don't understood a Lemma

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I was reading a book "Algebra" by M. Artin. A lemma was given in that I don't understood. Can you help me?

Lemma 2.7.6: Given an equivalence relation on a set $S$, the subsets of $S$ that are equivalence classes partition $S$.

Provide an example if possible.

Comment: Do you understand what an equivalence relation is? And what it means to partition a set?

Comment: @DavidRaveh Equivalence relation: a relation which is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

Comment: This is really a case where you start from the definitions, in this case of equivalence relation, equivalence class, and partition.

Comment: The title of your question does not contain any useful information.

Comment: Hi! I see you have already accepted an answer. But in the future, please (a) provide a more descriptive title (as Paul Frost suggested); and (b) make your problem more specific. E.g., what specifically don't you understand? And just as importantly, what *do* you understand? Presumably, you understand *some* of the terms in the lemma. Being more specific will make it easier for others to answer your question productively, and also help you avoid close-votes and down-votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a set $S$, a partition of $S$ is a collection $\{S_1,\dots ,S_n\}$ of non-empty subsets of $S$ such that $$\bigcup _{i=1}^n S_i=S$$ and $$S_i\cap S_j=\emptyset \text{ for $i\ne j$}$$

The result says that if $R$ is an equivalence relation on $S$ and $S_1,\dots, S_n$ are the equivalence classes of $R$, then $$\bigcup _{i=1}^n S_i=S$$ and $$S_i\cap S_j=\emptyset \text{ for $i\ne j$}$$

For example, consider the relation $a\sim b$ if and only if $a=b$ on the set $\{1, 2\}$. You can easily verify that this relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. Thus, it is an equivalence relation. The equivalence classes of this relation are the sets $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$. As you can see that $$\{1\}\cup \{2\}=\{1, 2\}$$ and $$\{1\}\cap \{2\}=\emptyset$$

The reverse direction of this result is also true. Namely, that if $R=\{S_1,\dots, S_n\}$ is a partition of $S$, then there is an equivalence relation on $S$ whose equivalence classes are the subsets in this partition.

I'll leave the proof of this direction for you to explore!

Edit: Fixed an important part of the theorem that I had mistakingly typed before.